# 2 basic Textmate shortcuts ‘don’t save’ and ‘replace all

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

Ok, maybe they're system shortcuts. I've googled (just a bit) and couldn't find an answer. Maybe there isn't any :) Still..

I love keyboard and I use quite a few in TextMate but just realise I still use the mouse for **2 of the most common actions**:

- How do I press **search and replace** after the S/R dialog box is up? - if you press enter it just takes you to the next occurrence of the search string
- when I close a file that I don't want to save, how can I choose **don't save** without touching the mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I press search and replace after the S/R dialog box is up? - if you press enter it just takes you to the next occurrence of the search string

The buttons in the box map to the same options under Edit > Find, so you can use those key shortcuts. So the Replace & Find button is <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, etc. You can also use some of the other selection items in Edit > Find. For example, if you have a word highlighted, you can use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to use that word as search text, and then <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to walk through occurrences of that word. You can also selected another word to use as replace text with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, then step through the occurrences (using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) and use Replace All in Selection (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) to replace. All these shortcuts are listed in Edit > Find for easy references.

> when I close a file that I don't want to save, how can I choose don't save without touching the mouse?

You can press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> as a shortcut for "Don't Save". Incidentally, this works in almost every document-based application on Mac OS X -- not *just* TextMate.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was typing exactly that but mipadi did it faster, however I’d like to add that the correct way to find and replace would be:

<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>

Type the word you want to replace, press <kbd>tab</kbd>, type the new word and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> will perform a “Replace All”.

Of course, minipadi’s solution works without bringing the Find dialog at all, which is, often preferred.

As for the second question, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> is for any save dialog (at least in Cocoa applications).